# Why does the read() function return an error?

Tags: c

I used the read() function to read the contents from a file but got a -1 return value. The file is not empty, I think it might be the problem of data type, but I am not sure. 
The contents of the file are like this:
1e00 000a 0600 0003 0100 0004 0300 0005
0800 0006 0900 0007 0b00 0003 0c00 0009
Thanks in advance.

```
#define swapFname "test.disk"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int diskfd;
    unsigned *buf;
    diskfd = open (swapFname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
    int location = (2-2) * 16 * 8 + 0*8; // 0
    int ret = lseek (diskfd, location, SEEK_SET);
    int retsize = read (diskfd, (char *)buf, 32);
    if (retsize < 0)
    { printf ("Error: Disk read returned incorrect size: %d\n", retsize); 
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: check trhe return value of `open`.

Comment: Check what is the `errno` set.

Comment: The file you want to open is relative to where the program executes. Is it there?

Comment: Another problem is that `buf` doesn't actually point to a buffer.

Comment: Note that if you have `buf` set up correctly, you don't need to cast it to `char *` in the call — the `read()` function takes a `void *` as the second argument, and any object pointer will be converted to a `void *` automatically.  Nominally, you're asking the compiler to cast twice.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, the return value is 3. open is okay, because I used the same way to write to the file, which succeeded.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are right, the problem is at the pointer, it should point to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue locally.  Having done so, I modified the program to be more informative about the nature of the problem: instead of printing a hand-rolled yet minimally-expressive error message, I used the `perror()` function to print a message that explains the specific nature of the error:

```
    if (retsize < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Running the resulting program produced this message:

> read: Bad address

This seems to be reporting on the problem that @MichaelBurr noted in his comment: you have declared `buf` as a pointer to `unsigned`, but you have not assigned it to point to anything.  As a result, it is a dangling pointer, and you should consider yourself lucky that the `read` function was able to recognize that, instead of (probably) clobbering random memory somewhere in your program's address space.  It seems likely that you instead want to declare `buf` as an *array*, maybe something like this:

```
    unsigned buf[16];
```

With that additional correction, the program no longer reported an error from `read()`.  That means it probably didn't have an error in `open()`, either, or in `lseek()`, but you ought to be testing each of those results individually.

Comment: Thank you John, it works! It is true that the buf should be assigned to a certain length.

Answer (score 0):

first I suggest to check you have *open the file correctly*, if the file have been opened check **`lseek`** if does not return -1, and later if you still wonder why you got -1 in read check **errno** in order to see the last error code.

Comment: These are good suggestions, but they do not constitute an answer to the question.

Comment: The open and lseek are both correct, the problem is at the pointer buf. Anyway, thanks.